# How to place replies in the same folder as the original message on the IMAP email app?

Tags: imap, stock-email-app

Messages that I reply to from my phone are placed in the "Sent" folder. Is it possible to configure the Email App to place replies in the same folder as the original message. Using galaxy S3, Android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, no, there is not a way to configure where sent mail is placed using the IMAP email account on the Galaxy S III. There may be a 3rd party email app that can do this, but not the stock one on the S III. As suggested in the comments [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9&feature) does what you want.

Comment: At least [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) lets you configure folders for Sent mail and others. Not sure about other mail apps.